# WPF ComboBox bind itemssource to different datacontext in MVVM

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, combobox

I have a user control that has its datacontext set to a view model called **EmployeeList_VM**.  I then have a ContentControl within that user-control that has its datacontect set to a public property (***EmployeeSelection***) of the view model.  The ContentControl's datacontext is the same as the selected item binding of a listbox within the same user control.

I want to have a combobox (of an observblecollection called **EmployeeStatus**) within the ContentControl bind its selecteditem to a property of the **EmployeeSelection** datacontext of the ContentControl.  I want the itemssource of the combobox to bind to a public property **EmployeeStatus** of the "parent" viewmodel **EmployeeList_VM**.

I can get a list of the employees status to appear wihtin the combobox.  I can not get it to bind to the idStatus property of the **EmployeeSelection**.

Here is What I have so far (some code removed for readability):

```
<UserControl x:Class="FTC.View.EmployeeListView"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FTC_Application"
            xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
            xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
            mc:Ignorable="d" 
            DataContext="{Binding EmployeeList_VM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
            d:DesignHeight="900" d:DesignWidth="1000">

        <Expander x:Name="DetailExpander" Grid.Column="2" Header="employee detail" Style="{DynamicResource ExpanderStyle_FTC}" IsExpanded="True" Padding="8,0,0,10" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                    <Button Content="" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonSave}" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" ToolTip="Save Changes" Margin="0,0,10,10"/>
                    <Button Content="" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonUndo}" Command="{Binding UndoCommand}" ToolTip="Undo Changes" Margin="0,0,10,10"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=EmployeeSelection, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                            <!-- FTC SETTINGS GRID CONTENT-->
                            <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="1">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock x:Name="SettingsHeading" Text="FTC Settings" Style="{StaticResource FTC_DetailHeading}" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>

                                <TextBlock Text="Status" Style="{StaticResource FTC_DetailLabelSub}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2"
                                          Margin="5,5,16,5" Height="37"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext.EmployeeStatus}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding idStatus, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                          SelectedValuePath="idStatus"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="chrCode" FontSize="18"/>

                           </Grid>
                    </ContentControl>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Expander>
</UserControl>
```

I even tried the following change (I named the ContentControl DetailControl) for the selected item of the combobox:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=DetailControl, Path=DataContext.idStatus}"
```

Can someone please help me get the selected item binding hooked up properly.  The combobox displays all the right items, but they do not bind to the EmployeeSelection.idStatus.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think if you remove `SelectedValuePath="idStatus"`, you should get what you're looking for. Didn't want to post this comment as an answer because I haven't done a lot of due diligence -- just looking at your XAML. Did you try that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

so here is what worked for me, hope it can help someone else

```
<ComboBox Name="cbStatus" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2"
                                          Style="{StaticResource FTC_DetailComboBox}"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext.EmployeeStatus}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=DetailControl, Path=DataContext.employee_status}"
                                          SelectedValuePath="idStatus"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding idStatus, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="chrCode"/>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you changed?

Comment: just look at the combobox declarations, it should be obvious

Comment: In ny case I had to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. Not sure why.