# WPF different dataContext for comboBox ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a ItemControl and inside I have a comboBox, what I'm trying to achieve is to have a different dataContext for the comboBox itemsSource

This is my itemControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" Margin="0,25,0,0" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel Margin="8">
                        <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                            <StackPanel >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Name:" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Width="70" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Type:" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext.EmployeeStatus}"
                                              SelectedValue="{Binding Type}" Width="70" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Units:" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Units}" Width="70" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Range:" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Range}" Width="70" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Scale:" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Scale}" Width="70" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Reason:" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Reason}" Width="70" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Description:" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Description}" Width="70" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I saw something similar but couldn't make the connection to my problem

[WPF ComboBox bind itemssource to different datacontext in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765046/wpf-combobox-bind-itemssource-to-different-datacontext-in-mvvm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution 1: Each ComboBox has different items***

You must create appropriate type with ComboBox items source.

Example:

```
public class MyType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Types { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Now you can binding ComboBox items source to different source:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" Margin="0,25,0,0" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel Margin="8">
                <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <StackPanel >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                            <TextBlock Text="Name:" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Width="70" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                            <TextBlock Text="Type:" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Types}"
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding Type}" Width="70" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        ...
</ItemsControl>
```

[Here](http://1drv.ms/1ne7uKD) you can find example solution.

***Solution 2: All ComboBox have the same items***

```
public class MyType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

class MyViewModel
{        
    private List<MyType> _types;
    public List<MyType> Types
    {
        get { return _types; }
        set { _types = value; }
    }
    public List<string> TypesItemsSource { get; set; }
}
```

XAML code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" Margin="0,25,0,0" >
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DockPanel Margin="8">
            <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <StackPanel >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                        <TextBlock Text="Name:" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Width="70" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                        <TextBlock Text="Type:" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.TypesItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding Type}" Width="70" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    ...
</ItemsControl>
```

[Here](http://1drv.ms/1i5yxa3) you can find example solution.

Comment: What this means? ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Types}"
The path is my answer?

Comment: @Yogevnn this means that each `ComboBox` has own ItemsSource in the source object.

Comment: But it is not possible for me to change the object that the entire itemsControl is reference to.
I need to change the dataContext of the comboBox so it will refer to my view model and the the model object

Comment: @Yogevnn each ComboBox will have different items source or all ComboBox will have the same items source from ViewModel ?

Comment: @Yogevnn check my answer again :)

Answer (score 0):

i use "marker interfaces" to find the right datacontext

```
public interface IDataContextMarker{} //just an empty interface
```

so within the view where your viewmodel is bound to implement this interface

```
public class MyView : IDataContextMarker {}
```

and now you can use the interface with relativesource binding instead of controls or ancestorlevel, that makes thing easier for some cases :)

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:IDataContextMarker}}, Path=DataContext.EmployeeStatus}"
```