# how to get the value of checkbox which is inside the combo box WPF?

Tags: wpf, checkbox, combobox

I have a combobox and the checkbox is present inside the combobox. I want the value of the multi selection checkbox. My code:

```
<ComboBox Name="LocationFilterComboBox" Width="100" SelectedItem="{Binding LocationValue}">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate >
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding LocationValue}"  IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=all, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="120" />
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Back-end code:

```
//code to get the value
public partial class Location
{
    #region Property
    private string LOCAID;
    public string LocaId
    {
        get
        {
            return LOCAID;
        }
        set
        {
            value = LOCAID;
        }
    }

    private string LOCADESC;
    public string LocationValue
    {
        get
        {
            return LOCADESC;
        }
        set
        {
            value = LOCADESC;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
}

//code for binding the location
public IList<Location> BindAllLocation()
{
    if (Repository != null) Repository.Dispose();
    Repository = GetInvoiceRepository();
    IList<Location> locationList = Repository.GetLocations(((App)Application.Current).DataContextFactory);

    return locationList;
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LocationFilterComboBox.ItemsSource = BindAllLocation();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You already using bindings. Your value should be in the property `IsChecked` assuming to your binding ;)

Comment: an u share example of code
how can i retrive checked item @MightyBadaboom

Comment: @AkhilJain Please post code we can use for an example.

Comment: @lightlike code updated

Comment: @AkhilJain Sorry. I mean the structure (Properties,...) you bind to.

Comment: updated @lightlike

Answer (score 1):

I would not set the ItemsSource directly. Try binding it:

```
private ObservableCollection<Location> _locationList = new ObservableCollection<Location>();
public ObservableCollection<Location> LocationList
{
    get { return _locationList; };
    set
    {
        if (_locationList == value)
            return;
        _locationList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
}

private Location _currentLocation;
public Location CurrentLocation
{
    get { return _currentLocation; };
    set
    {
        if (_currentLocation == value)
            return;
        _currentLocation = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
}

public IList BindAllLocation()
{
    if (Repository != null) Repository.Dispose();
        Repository = GetInvoiceRepository();
    IList<Location> locationList = Repository.GetLocations(((App)Application.Current).DataContextFactory);
    return locationList;
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in BindAllLocation())
        LocationList.Add(item);
}
```

In Xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding *binding to LocationList*}" Width="100" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentLocation}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding LocationValue}"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="120" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I do not know the DataContext on the ComboBox so if you have Problems with that try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765046/wpf-combobox-bind-itemssource-to-different-datacontext-in-mvvm).

Then you can sort out the selected Values using:

```
var result = LocationList.Where(x => x.IsChecked);
```

Of course you have to have a IsChecked Property for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `IsChecked` property of each `CheckBox` in the `ComboBox` is bound to the `IsChecked` property of the "all" `CheckBox`, you should be able to get the value directly from this one:

```
bool isChecked = all.IsChecked;
```

The other option would otherwise be to add a `bool` property to the `Location` class and bind to this one:

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding LocationValue}"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Width="120" />
```

You could then get the value of each individual `CheckBox` in the `ComboBox` by simply iterating over its `ItemsSource`:

```
foreach(var location in LocationFilterComboBox.Items.OfType<Location>())
{
    bool isChecked = location.IsChecked;
}
```